# How can I have my page access functions from a .vb file in App_Code?

Tags: asp.net

I made a new page in our website that needs to access some functions that are in App_Code/modFunctions.vb. I tried simply calling the functions but it says not found in current context. So here are the file locations, starting at the root of the site:

```
/App_Code/ModFunctions.vb
/users/export.aspx
```

export.aspx is my C# page that I need to call the functions in ModFunctions.vb, how can I link them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access the functions inside App_Code with no trouble. Make sure to either qualify it with the namespace or do an Import of the namespace.

If that doesn't work for you, post code on how/what you are trying.